# Angular - Filter for ng-repeat not working properly for objects in array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Suppose I have the following array of Objects:

```
 $scope.users = [{id: 1, username: "jon", expired: true},
                 {id: 2, username: "adam", expired: false},
                 {id: 3, username: "jeff", expired: false}]
```

I'm trying to build a table that is filtered on expired accounts:

```
 <table class ="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      th>ID</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in users |filter: x.expired == true">
      <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.username }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

However the table above is blank. How can I fix the filter?

Answer (score 2):

Filter expression should be placed as object.

```
ng-repeat="x in users | filter: { expired : true}"
```